# Add checkmark image to multiple array of buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton, nsarray

I am trying to add a checkmark button when user select a button, so I create two `IBOutletColletion` both for `buttons` and `check mark image` :
[image]

The next step is when user select each of of buttons a checkmark image appears on above of each image,So in this part I have a problem which is checkmarks all show and all hide ! not when user select the specific button . Here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 

//Hide checkmarks when app opens 
 for (UIImageView*checkMark in _checkMarkArray) {

                         checkMark.alpha = 0;
    }
}





- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {
          for (UIButton*button in _ButtonsArray) {

                    if (sender == button) {

                         for (UIImageView*checkMark in _checkMarkArray) {

                             checkMark.alpha = 1;
                         }
                    }

                }
        }
```

Comment: Why dont you use 2 images for the button and simply toggle the background image of the button ?

Answer (score 2):

Use Tag (Where Button and Above image tag are same)

```
 - (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {

                     for (UIImageView*checkMark in _checkMarkArray) {
                      if(sender.tag == Checkmark.tag && sender.isSelected)
                      {
                        checkMark.alpha = 1;
                       }
                      if(sender.tag == Checkmark.tag && !sender.isSelected)
                      {
                        checkMark.alpha = 0;
                       }
                     }
            }
    }
```

better solution

create Two image 
one with only Heart and another image is heart With Checkmark

set Only heart image in button's Normal state (deSelected)
and set combined image in selected state

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I would suggest is to create a custom `UIButton` class, which contains two `UIImageViews`. In the button action method make the checkmark image hidden or visible accordingly. In this case you just need two images, one heart image and one tick image.

Your CustomButton.h will look something like this :-

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *checkMarkImageView, *backgroundImageView;
```

Give proper frames for the ImageViews in CustomButton.m file. Now in the view or view controller where you are planning to give the button action, change the checkmark image view's state accordingly. So the button action will look something like this :-

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
   if (sender.checkMarkImageView.hidden == YES)
       sender.checkMarkImageView.hidden = NO;
   else
       sender.checkMarkImageView.hidden = YES;
}
```